# How to encode value to put in iframe src attribute to prevent XSS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, xss

Using ASP.NET MVC, I have an url that takes a querystring param called path, which can be a url within my site.  I found a XSS vulnerability and I cannot figure out how to encode the path value correctly to prevent XSS (but not do a lot of code to whitelist acceptable urls)

So the url that the user visits is:

```
/iFrame?path=mypage.aspx
```

The XSS can be seen like this:

```
/iFrame?path=javascript:alert%281%29
```

The HTML for the iFrame that uses the path querystring value is:

```
<iframe src="@Model.Source"></iframe>
```

I've also tried:

Both of those methods still display the javascript alert box.

Is there a built in encoder for ASP.NET MVC that will encode it so that the src will not execute javascript? Or do I need to do a some whitelisting or other methods to protect against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend reading [Preventing Open Redirection Attacks (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks) which talks about using the IsLocalUrl() method from the ASP.NET MVC 3 UrlHelper class:

```
public bool IsLocalUrl(string url) {
  return System.Web.WebPages.RequestExtensions.IsUrlLocalToHost(
    RequestContext.HttpContext.Request, url);
}
```

IsUrlLocalToHost() method from the System.Web.WebPages RequestExtensions class:

```
public static bool IsUrlLocalToHost(this HttpRequestBase request, string url)
{
  return !url.IsEmpty() &&
      ((url[0] == '/' && (url.Length == 1 ||
       (url[1] != '/' && url[1] != '\\'))) ||   // "/" or "/foo" but not "//" or "/\"
       (url.Length > 1 &&
        url[0] == '~' && url[1] == '/'));   // "~/" or "~/foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the URL and whitelist the protocol.

Call `Uri.TryParse()`, and reject any URL for which that returns false, or has a protocol other than HTTP or HTTPS.

You also need to decide whether to allow relative URLs.

Comment: I did not downvote. I chose Erik's answer because of the ease of use.

Comment: @slolife: Yes; his answer is better.  (assuming you don't want to allow any absolute URLs)